# To Return a True Value if Pattern Match is Found Else Return a False Value

Tags: search

Suppose I am searching for **pattern** in my text file using vim. Is there a way to store 0 in a variable *foo* if no matches to **pattern** are found and store 1 if at least 1 match is found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29) function:

> When a match has been found its line number is returned. If there is no match a 0 is returned and the cursor doesn't move.  No error message is given.

You probably want to set the `c`, `w`, and `n` flags:

> `c`     accept a match at the cursor position
>   `n`     do Not move the cursor
>   `w`     wrap around the end of the file

```
:echo search('search', 'cwn')
5127
:echo search('jabberwocky', 'cwn')
0
```

If you really want only `0` and `1` add `> 0`:

```
:echo search('search', 'cwn') > 0
1
:echo search('jabberwocky', 'cwn') > 0
0
```

If you want, you can of course make a function for this:

```
fun! HasPattern(p)
    return search(a:p, 'cwn') > 0
endfun
```

Or even a command:

```
:command! -nargs=1 HasPattern :echo search(<f-args>, 'cwn')>0

:HasPattern search
1
:HasPattern jabberwocky
0
```